# ¿Cómo devolver formato de fecha dd/MM/yyyy usando materialdatepicker android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Quisiera saber como devolver a mi `TextInputEditText` el valor seleccionado de mi MaterialDatePicker en formato dd/MM/yyyy  13/06/2020 ya que lo devuelve de esta forma `13 Jun. 2020`.

Aquí mi código:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ES");
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

                MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
                builder.setTitleText("Seleccionar Fecha");
                final MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker = builder.build();

                materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"DATE_PICKER");
                materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPositiveButtonClick(Object selection) {
                        txtDpicker.setText(materialDatePicker.getHeaderText());
                    }
                });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes convertir el formato obtenido al formato deseado usando la clase `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
   public void onPositiveButtonClick(Object selection) {

       String inputFormat = "dd MMM yyyy";
       String outputFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
              
       String inputDate = materialDatePicker.getHeaderText(); //"13 Jun 2020";
           
       String outputDate = inputDate;
       try {
            outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat, LOCALE_MX).format(new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, LOCALE_MX).parse(inputDate));
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("formateDateFromstring(): " + e.getMessage());
           outputDate = "";
       }

                        
      txtDpicker.setText(outputDate);

  }
```

Tendrìas un valor de salida en la variable `outputDate` con el formato deseado:

```
13/06/2020
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono a la perfección